# grid-columns inside media queries not working for html article element?

Tags: html, css, css-grid, article

Grid-columns doesn't seem to be working for my `article` element, but does for my `nav`.

CSS

```css
/*sm-md*/
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
    .signup-btn, .login-btn{
        font-size: 1.4em !important;
    }
    .listitem{
        font-size: 1.7em !important;
    }
    nav{
        grid-column: 4/15;
    }
    article{
        grid-column: 4/17;
    }
}

article{
    grid-column: 2/10;
    height: auto;
    th: 100%;
    margin: 30px 0 0 0;
    border-radius: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 10px #0000001a;
    padding-inline: 30px;
}

nav{
    grid-column: 7/14;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Not sure what's the problem here?

```
<main class="grid-container main">
    <article class="grid-wrapper article">
        content
    </article>
    <aside class="grid-wrapper aside">
        content
    </aside>
</main>
```

Already searched documents and tried changing up things.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to superpose the *article* and the *nav* in a grid. `grid-column` is supposed to contain the starting column and the ending one. If the *article* is in `grid-column: 2/10;` once you declare `grid-column: 7/14;` for the *nav* it cannot still work if there are in the same grid.
The *nav* in not shown in your html and the css is not helping that much without the classes declared like `.grid-container` or `.main` for example, so it's possible I misunderstood the configuration.

Also:

- the media query **should be declared after** your root css to not be replaced by it. **<- this is probably your problem**

```
article{ // default case
    grid-column: 2/10;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px){
    article{
        grid-column: 4/17; // this override the previous definition if it matches the media query
    }
}
```

- `th` is not a css property.